# Syntax null conditional operator jagged array

Tags: c#, null, jagged-arrays

How is the correct syntax of a null conditional operator within a jagged array?

```
int[][][] array = new int[5][][];
// fill with data here
bool result = array[0]?.[3]?.[2] ?? == 3;
```

The reference doesn't provide any information about that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool result = array?[0]?[3]?[2] == 3;
```

Comment: The first `?` is redundant this should works `array[0]?[3]?[2]`

Comment: @S.Akbari no in case of `array == null` +1 for handling even that case